# Hi, can I infinite click with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

Is there any way I can autoclick (spam) a button on a webpage using selenium? What I tried was `while True: driver.find_element_by_id("whatev").click()`

Comment: OK, what's wrong with this code?

Comment: @prophet that it will break the internet?

Comment: infinity is very long, you may want to stop sooner

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Most odds this will work. However, some sites may have protection against long auto clicking. In such case the site will redirect you to another URL, or a new HTML will be loaded with other classes, IDs and other attributes that will fail your code.

Here is what you can do using Java, translate my code to python:

```
loadSite();

while (true) {
  try {
    driver.find_element_by_id("whatev").click() 
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    loadSite();
    driver.find_element_by_id("whatev").click() 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!!!

Comment: @pol If my answer helped you - then you may give me an upvote. Glad to help.

Comment: sorry, I tried but it said "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."

Comment: @pol Yes, you need at least 15 reputation points. Once you get there please don't forget me.